# Kotlin - declare a generic class with a type param which is generic

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have a BasePresenter class like so. BaseMvpView is an interface

```
open class BaseMvpPresenter<View : BaseMvpView> {
}
```

I am trying to create a BaseMvpActivity class which is parameterized with a BaseMvpPresenter like so:

```
abstract class BaseMvpActivity<T : BaseMvpPresenter> : BaseActivity(), BaseMvpView {
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
One type argument expected for class BaseMvpPresenter<View: BaseMvpView>
```

How do I properly declare this? I want to be able to use BaseMvpActivity as so:

```
abstract class BaseMvpActivity<T : BaseMvpPresenter<U>, U : BaseMvpView> : BaseActivity(), BaseMvpView {

    abstract var presenter: T

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        presenter.onViewCreated(this)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        presenter.onViewDestroyed()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter to the `BaseMVPPresenter`. You can add a second parameter to your abstract class as follows

```
abstract class BaseMvpActivity<V: BaseMvpView, T : BaseMvpPresenter<V>> : BaseActivity(), BaseMvpView {
}
```

so lets say you're creating a view to show posts, then you would do something like this:

```
class Activity : BaseMVPActivity<PostsView, PostPresenter<PostView>() {
    //Here comes your code
}
```

Hope this helps :)